# Is there a difference between RP2040 pins and pi pico pins?

Tags: embedded, display, rp2040

I’m trying to make an embedded system with a RP2040 chip at the center. I’m trying to connect a display to the RP2040 and all I can find is pico diagrams, so aside from pins that don’t exist on the pico, do they have the same pinout?

Comment: Please provide circuit diagram links to the relevant bits. Add to those diagrams clear identifiers that show where the interface is to be made.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the RP2040 chip and the Pi Pico module do not have the same pinout because they are different shapes. The pins are in different places so they couldn't possibly be in the same places.

If you look at the [Pi Pico schematic on page 24](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/pico/pico-datasheet.pdf) you can see how how the Pi Pico circuit board is wired. It does show the physical arrangement of both the RP2040 chip and the Pi Pico connector, and where the GPIOs are connected on each. When two wires have the same label (such as "GPIO10") it means they are connected together, even though the connecting wire is not drawn on the schematic to reduce clutter.